# Is it possible to be considered a dual status alien even with if you meet substantial presence test?

Tags: united-states, taxes, h-1b-visa, dual-status

I moved to the US on January 3rd 2014, and stayed there for most of the year (~273 days). I'm still living in the US. I seem to meet the substantial presence test (right?), but for some reason after calling the IRS, they told me I should file under Dual Status because I was considered a non-resident for Jan 1 and 2 2014.

Is the IRS person correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're correct.

From the [IRC Sec. 7701(b)(2)(A)(iii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7701):

> Residency starting date for individuals meeting substantial presence
>   test In the case of an individual who meets the substantial presence
>   test of paragraph (3) with respect to any calendar year, the residency
>   starting date shall be the first day during such calendar year on
>   which the individual is present in the United States.

You can still claim deductions, just not the standard deduction.

Answer (score 1):

They are correct assuming that you were nonresident for all of 2013. See [First Year of Residency](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222164).

However, if you're married, then you have the option to become a resident alien for all of 2014 and file jointly with your spouse. To do this, you would use either [Choosing Resident Alien Status](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222177) (if your spouse is resident or dual status for 2014) or [Nonresident Spouse Treated as Resident](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222193) (if your spouse is nonresident for 2014).